# how to connect to aws rds postgresql ssl with prisma

Tags: prisma

I am using `nextjs13.2.4` and `prisma5.0.0`. ssl cert updated in aws rds causing error in connection. run the existing code as is, `Error: P1011: Error opening a TLS connection: handshake failure will occur.`

`datasource db { provider = "postgresql" url      = env("DATABASE_URL") }`

The solution I tried was to receive the `.pem` file from Certificate bundles at the bottom of `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html` and modify the `DATABASE_URL` of `.env`.

Before DATABASE_URL
`postgresql://myuser:mypass@myurl:5432/mydb?charset=utf8`

After
`postgresql://myuser:mypass@myurl:5432/mydb?charset=utf8&sslcert=cert.pem`

`cert.pem` renamed the `pem` file downloaded from Aws and placed it in the prisma folder.

add the `cert.pem` file and run it, the error message will change.

`Error: P1011: Error opening a TLS connection: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.`

Afterwards, I looked at `https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2676` and added the `p12` file, but the error messages are all the same.

It was working fine before I updated the ssl certificate in aws.